# testing react google maps useJsApiLoader using react testing library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, react-google-maps

I have this basic component, but whenever I try testing it with React Testing Library the only thing present on the screen is the `div` with the "loading" text. I think this is because `isLoaded` might not have a value when the component is first loaded.

How do I tell React Testing Library to wait until `isLoaded` is `true` so it can find other elements on the page?

```js
import {
  GoogleMap,
  useJsApiLoader,
  Autocomplete,
  Marker,
} from "@react-google-maps/api";

export const Map = () => {
  const { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader("apikey");
  return isLoaded ? (
    <form>
      <Autocomplete />
      <GoogleMap>
        <Marker />
      </GoogleMap>
    </form>
  ) : (
    <div>loading</div>
  );
};

export default Map;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to stub the `isLoaded` in `useJsApiLoader`.

Something like this approach (I've not tested this and you'd need to adjust the assertions to your requirements)...

```js
import { screen, render } from "@testing-library/react";
import Map from "./Map";
import * as ReactGoogleMapsApi from "@react-google-maps/api";

describe("Map", () => {
  it("shows loader", () => {
    jest
      .spyOn(ReactGoogleMapsApi, "useJsApiLoader")
      .mockReturnValue({
        isLoaded: false
      });
    render(<Map />);

    expect(screen.getByText(/loading/i)).toBeInDocument();
  });

  it("shows map", () => {
    jest
      .spyOn(ReactGoogleMapsApi, "useJsApiLoader")
      .mockReturnValue({
        isLoaded: true
      });
    render(<Map />);

    expect(screen.getByText(/some map content/i)).toBeInDocument();
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm getting an `ReferenceError: google is not defined` when I try to run that. Error happens on line `render(<Map />);`

Comment: If you replace the `<GoogleMap><Marker /></GoogleMap>` from `<Map/>` with just text content, e.g. 'some map content', do you still get the error?  I'm not sure of the internals of @react-google-maps/api but you may need to do some further mocking of the other @react-google-maps/api dependencies to get it working.

Comment: @Kerron you can mock `google` namespace using `global` object, for example `global.google = { maps: { Map: jest.fn(), Marker: jest.fn() } } as unknown as typeof google;`

Comment: I had to use this import { initialize } from '@googlemaps/jest-mocks';
Also add the initilize() wrapped in beforeEach